# JSON returned from http handler is null in IE8 but not IE10 or Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the following JavaScript

```
patients.prototype.GetPatient = function(patient_id,callback)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var fullpath;

    try {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var pat = parseJson(xmlhttp.response);

                if (pat) {
                    callback(parseJson(xmlhttp.response));
                }
                else {
                    alert('Null object returned?');
                }
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.status == 404) {
                alert('Unable to find Retrieve Patient Service');
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "RetrievePatient.ashx?PatientId=" + patient_id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Unable to retrieve requested patient details');
    }
}

function parseJson(jsonString) {
    var res;

    try {

        alert('Parsing JSON');

        res = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Call to evaluate result failed with error ' + e.message + ' Evaluating Json ' + jsonString );
    };


    return res;
}
```

If this is run from a page running on IE10 I get the patient details back correctly. If I run it on Chrome likewise it returns back the details of the patient, but if I run it on a page in IE8 the JSON is null and the whole thing falls down.

Anyone know what I can do to make this work in IE8?

Comment: Are you serving the page from your file system?

Comment: No. I have a Generic Handler (extension .ashx) which queries a database and returns the results as JSON. Under IE8 xmlhttp.response is coming back as undefined

Comment: Is the page in standards mode, or quirks mode?

Comment: Don't know to be honest. I really need it to work regardless as I have no control of the IE installation

Comment: Does your document have a doctype declaration at the top? If not, you'll be in quirks mode. You can also control this via a `<meta>` tag or (perhaps better) via HTTP headers.

Comment: I put a DOCTYPE declaration at the top of the page <!doctype html> - but think I have found it - in IE8 the property is responseText and not response. I'm getting another error but will investigate that further.

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice that. If you use `response` (where supported) it'll try to automatically parse the data. If you're going to parse it yourself, then `responseText` gives you the raw data.

Comment: Check your JSON for loose trailing commas. I've found that modern browsers are forgiving of it, but it will break in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do a check for null before attempting to parse. Also, add a check for undefined

```
function parseJson(jsonString) {
   var res;

   if (jsonString == undefined) {
       return jsonString;
   }

   if (jsonString == null) {
       return jsonString;
   }

   if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
       res = JSON.parse(jsonString);
       return res;
   }

}
```